# Extremely difficult exercise Apostol calculus 1 (I 3.5 Ex.10)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, proof-verification

Cannot prove this:

> If $x$ has the property that $0 \leq x < h$ for every positive real
>   number $h$, then $x = 0$.

I tried proving this by contradiction, by setting $x > 0$. However, it lead me nowhere.

There are other answers which suggest we take $h = \frac{x}{2}$ and simply show $0 < x/2 < x$, which is contradiction, but this is plain wrong (in my opinion). $x$ denotes a set, and by choosing $h = x/2$, there still exists some $0 < x_2 < x/2$. $x$ is a notation for a set, since Apostol says "**x has a property**" in the exercise above^. Wiki difines it as

> In mathematics, a property is any characteristic that applies to a
>   given set

Comment: Wikipedia is not your textbook, though, perhaps it could be worded more clearly. Certainly Apostol means: *Let $x$ be a number such that $0\leq x<h$ for any $h>0$. Then $x=0$.* The problem you’re running into is that definitions and notation doesn’t have to be consistent from book to book (a lot of notation is standard, but definitions vary quite often).

Comment: @Clayton, ok, and thanks. So if $x$ is predefined single number, then the solution should really be simply taking $h \leq x$. Well, that is a bummer, spent 1 hour trying to prove it :(

Comment: @John The actual form of the argument depends on how real number have been defined. For example, if they are defined as [Dedekind cuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_cut), then you have to show that if $x\subset y$ for all cuts $y$ such that $0\subset y$. Then $x=0$. There is work to be done. You can follow the suggestion of looking at the set $\frac{1}{2}x$ consisting of the elements of $x$ divided by $2$. You need to prove that that is a cut, that it is contained in $x$ and that it strictly contains the cut $0$.

Comment: Apostol says "You may use Axioms 1 through 9 and Theorems I.1 through I.25". Have you gone through those axioms and theorems?

Answer (score 2):

I think the suggestion solves your problem.

Put 
\begin{equation}
A=\{ x \in \mathbb{R}; 0\leq x< h, \;\forall h>0\}.
\end{equation}
If $x > 0$ and $x \in A$ then $\frac{x}{2} >0$ and we can choose $h=\frac{x}{2}$. By definition we will have to have \begin{equation}
0<x<\frac{x}{2}.
\end{equation} 
From there we have \begin{equation}
x<\frac{x}{2} \; => \; 2x<x \;=>\; x<0,
\end{equation}
 thats your contradiction.

Comment: Thx, but the issue was notational here.